# Remove the 'audio' and 'sound' tags

Tags: discussion, tag-removal-request

The [audio](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio) and [sound](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sound) tags aren't needed on Sound Design, since every question on this site *should* be about audio and sound. Some of these were added during the migration from AVP, but both tags existed previously.

I intend to remove both tags completely (and blacklist them) on Wednesday, February 5, after fixing posts that would be difficult to spot / scope otherwise.

If you'd like to give a hand, just jump into both tags and see if you find posts where:

- It's the *only* tag applied - in which case edit / suggest an edit to apply better tags
- The post itself could use some help or cleanup, in which case edit / flag appropriately as needed

And, what mass tag removal would be complete without a one-armed dragon?

[image: troggy]

After which, Trogador will do what he does best :)

Comment: I agree - is there a way to take out those tags completely without flooding the front page?