# Please help add tags to questions only tagged sound or audio

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retagging

In [an earlier announcement](https://sound.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49/remove-the-audio-and-sound-tags), I indicated that I planed to remove the meta-tags [audio](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio) and [sound](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sound). I've gone through these and added tags where I could when either tag was the only tag on a question, but I'm starting to reach the limits of my domain knowledge.

Also, I'm running into situations where I find tags that might fit, but are also not great tags, and will probably go soon after these do, which just leads to a circular problem :)

If you have some time and want to do something awesome for the site, go through the list of questions tagged with either [audio](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio) or [sound](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sound), and find a better, more descriptive tag to apply to these. You can remove the problematic tag in the process.

If none exists, or the existing tags you're turning up all seem equally horrible (they could conceivably fit any question on the site) - you can leave an answer here with a suggestion to create a new, better tag, and a link to the post where it could be applied. I'll be checking this pretty much daily to make sure good suggestions keep rolling along.

Thanks to all that want to help! When we're done, we'll be much better organized, and probably *much* better indexed when it comes to search engines.

Comment: Is there a way to search for e.g. questions with the [audio] tag and specifically no other tags?

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to search for just one tag, but found scrolling through the 24 pages that it was easy to see those with just one tag.

Answer (score 2):

I have done all of the [audio](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio) ones except 9 which are all about editing audio in video suites. They have all been deleted here and sent back to Video.

I have also edited all those that just had the [sound](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sound) to either replace that tag with something more appropriate, or add a suitable tag.

Comment: You, sir, are awesome. I'm just sayin'